# Deploying to the Crashlytics Beta service from an Xcode Bot

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, crashlytics, xcode-bots

I'm trying to use the command line deployment method to upload an iOS beta to Crashlytics (Crashlytics.framework/submit) in a post archive step using an Xcode Bot on Xcode Server.

The problem is that Crashlytics doesn't appear to be able to sign the ipa file correctly.

According to their support i need to unlock the keychain. I have tried the following but the error persists:

- `security unlock-keychain -p the-password /Library/Keychains/System.keychain`
- Unlocking the keychain via the server GUI (Keychain Access)
- Running security list-keychains only lists `/Library/Keychains/System.keychain` and the certificate and private key are imported and present in that keychain.

The error:

```
2015-02-04 10:43:06.247 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.1 (11)
2015-02-04 10:43:06.981 submit Crashlytics: Unable to find a certificate with a private key: Error Domain=CLSProvisioningProfileErrorDomain Code=-1 "The operation couldn�t be completed. (CLSProvisioningProfileErrorDomain error -1.)" UserInfo=0x10020e250 {Details=iPhone Distribution: ****** (*****), SourcePath=/var/folders/rk/758w2bp12sq1lh5q5mrj598h000087/T/upload/Payload/our.bundle.id/embedded.mobileprovision}
2015-02-04 10:43:07.002 submit Crashlytics: Failed to prepare the binary for release
Error uploading to Crashlytics
```

Maybe the issue has something to do with the Xcode Bot running as another user called `_xsomething`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. You should point to the `login.keychain`. Most cases you have your credentials (certificate and private key) in your `login.keychain`, NOT your `System.keychain`. Remember, a keychain is just a file encrypted with the credentials. You should tell to the post action run script (after `Crashlytics/submit` execution) which keychain should use. 
You can find more info on this thread: **https://twittercommunity.com/t/problem-submitting-to-crashlytics-beta-from-xcode-server/31703**

Cheers!